# UIView autoresizingMask for fixed left and right margin and flexible width

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I can't figure it out how to resize width with fixed left and right margin.[image: Autoresize xCode]

I don't find any fixed led/right margin APIs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In code, to get a view to have fixed left and right margins along with flexible width you can do the following:

```
UIView *parentView = self.view; // adjust as needed
CGRect bounds = parentView.bounds; // get bounds of parent view
CGRect subviewFrame = CGRectInset(bounds, 20, 0); // left and right margin of 20
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subviewFrame];
subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[parentView addSubview:subview];
```

Adjust as needed to create your actual subview. Adjust the `subviewFrame` to match your desired margins.

As answered, this will give your subview fixed left and right margins of 20 points each and a flexible width. When setting the `autoresizingMask`, any component not set as flexible is automatically fixed (almost). This means the top margin and height are also fixed (since they are not set). The bottom margin is made implicitly flexible since the top margin and height are fixed. All three values going across or up/down can't be fixed at the same time for obvious reasons.

Comment: Not tricky at all. It's actually quite simple. The fixed margins will be Whatever the subview's margins are, relative to its parent view, when you create the view. That's it. Give the subview a flexible width and you are done.

Comment: not tricky, it's just that UIView created in code have a different default than the one used in IB. Which can lead on some confusion.